# What are good references for the different methods of combining p-values?

Tags: p-value, references, combining-p-values

I need a good reference for the methods and/or the difficulties that arise when attempting such a combination.

I've found Loughin, TM, [A systematic comparison of methods for combining p-values from independent tests](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947303002950), *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis* (2004) 47(3):467–485, for example. Is there a better/more precise one?

Comment: Is this for multiple test correction or something else?

Comment: It's pretty long to explain but basically I have 3 `p-values` obtained through the same process (the `kde.test` function of R's `ks` package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/ks.pdf) but applied to three different sets of 2 columns each (all 6 columns are linked because they belong to the same 'observation')

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a meta analysis.  Fisher's combination test is one method for combining p-values.  There are many books on meta analysis that could be useful to you. I will give you an answer with links to several books if you tell me I am on the right track.

Comment: Well I'm not a statistician so I have no idea what a meta analysis is :) (sorry) I actually do not want to perform such a combination, I just need references for the various methods of doing so and/or its difficulties (like the article I presented, to which I have no access sadly)

Comment: I guess I don't know why you are interested in the article. They talk in the abstract about combining p-values for a combined hypothesis. If you are combining independent data set to reach strong conclusion because of the increased sample size. That is all that us meant by a meta analysis. One way to do meta analysis (also called data synthesis) is to combined p-values from independent tests of the individual data sets. Fisher's combination test is one of many that could be tried. Apparently the paper compares 6 such methods.  Meta analysis is in the list of key words in the abstract.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to find out that Fisher's test is one that they compare.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I mentioned the article because it mentions several methods of combining p-values. As I said, I'm not really interested in performing such a combination, rather I'm looking for sources to reference the various methods for, and/or complications of, doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One useful entry into this literature is an annotated bibliography by R D Cousins which considers most of the well-known methods for combining $p$-values
and which is [freely available from arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.2209).

Comment: (+1) What is the benefit of using BibTeX on this forum? Presumably that one can copy-paste it into one's .bib file. How often do you think this is happening? I would guess that many many more people would find a hyper-link more useful; my own preference is to put a hyperlink on a short citation, e.g. `Cousins, 2008, Annotated bibliography of some papers on combining significances or $p$-values` or something like that. Perhaps a BibTeX citation can be provided extra in the end of an answer. I am saying this because this is not the first time you are using BibTeX and I am always wondering...

Comment: Thank you for the article mdewey. I edited your answer to add a link since I also wondered (as @amoeba did) why you left the bibtex instead (or without) the link.

Comment: I would suggest to follow the advice of @amoeba and not embed BibTex for citations here. Assuming you actually *do* want a BibTeX citation to be available, you could cite via a [Google Scholar hyperlink](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=12388032574443842317&hl=en&as_sdt=0,44). If you click that link, then click Cite, then BibTex, you can get the same result.

Comment: @amoeba (and other commenters) apologies, I had no idea I was going to perturb so many people. I have removed the formatting.