# Combining p values: what can we say about population of studies

Tags: p-value, population, combining-p-values

I have N p values (N is around 200) one for each of N independent experiments in my study. 
These p values range from 0.03 to 0.7 (mean is 0.3), where only 5% of p values are less than 0.05. If I look at the fraction of experiments where the null hypothesis is rejected I get this 5%, meaning that for the majority of the study (95%) the null hypothesis was not rejected.

If I combine p values using different methods (Fisher's, Stouffer's ect.) the resulting p value is lower than 0.05, suggesting that the null hypotheses are not true for every experiment, but that is what I see from the p values when I obtained them... 
I would like to get a measure that will reflect a general trend in the study. Do you think that "rejection rate" is a valid way to report it? Or maybe you have any idea what is the appropriate measure for this?

Thank you!

Comment: 5% of p-values below 0.05 is what we would expect if the null hypothesis were true. Therefore, at first glance, it seems that you haven't found any significant effect.

Comment: And the relevant xkcd link: https://xkcd.com/882/ (probably, the most linked xkcd strip in Cross Validated).

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible for the methods to combine $p$-values to give a value less than a certain criterion even if all the $p$-values being combined are above the criterion. Se this extended [Can a meta-analysis of studies which are all "not statistically signficant" lead to a "significant" conclusion?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243003/can-a-meta-analysis-of-studies-which-are-all-not-statistically-signficant-lead) Q&A.

What you are testing is the null hypothesis that they are drawn from a uniform distribution on the unit interval.
Unfortunately there are
two classes of alternative hypothesis
(1) $H_A$: all $p_i$ have the same (unknown)
non--uniform, non--increasing density,
(2) $H_B$:
at least one $p_i$ has an (unknown)
non--uniform, non--increasing density.
This may explain why there are so many candidate methods for combining the
$p_i$.

There are some references about comparing the methods in [What are good references for the different methods of combining p-values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38099/what-are-good-references-for-the-different-methods-of-combining-p-values?rq=1) Q&A.